# How to fetch data without for-loop?

Tags: sqlite, dart, flutter, async-await, sqflite

Here I stored one by one value. API has 1 million data. Response time is 3 seconds Storing cache takes a lot of time.

How can I add all data once like select insert query?

```
storeDefCatMaster(String url,String token) async {
  final response = await http.get(
    '${url}/v1.0/DefCatMaster',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${token}'},
  );
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  DefCatMaster model = DefCatMaster.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  int length = model.data.length;

  for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    var data = DataDefCatMaster(
      deF_CAT_ID: model.data[i].deF_CAT_ID,
      description: model.data[i].description,
      in_use: model.data[i].in_use,
      sortOrder: model.data[i].sortOrder
    );
    await helper.insert(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625442/how-to-display-variable-from-json-return-in-text?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: I already did this part. my problem is when storing data long time to store

Comment: then store sharedpreference or sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is batch excution api provided by sqflite which reduces back and forth between native and dart code, this might improve performance.

Example code:

```dart
batch = db.batch();
batch.insert('Test', {'name': 'item'});
batch.update('Test', {'name': 'new_item'}, where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: ['item']);
batch.delete('Test', where: 'name = ?', whereArgs: ['item']);
results = await batch.commit();
```

Bulk insert like this:

```dart
batch = db.batch();
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    var data = DataDefCatMaster(
      deF_CAT_ID: model.data[i].deF_CAT_ID,
      description: model.data[i].description,
      in_use: model.data[i].in_use,
      sortOrder: model.data[i].sortOrder
    );
    batch.insert('table_name', data);
  }
results = await batch.commit(); 
//or
//await batch.commit(noResult: true);
// if you dont want result, this will improve performance as well.
```

You still will be using for loop but the performance would be much better with the above mentioned code.

Comment: data is coming from server within 3 seconds but storing cache time is 10minutes. I dont know why it is

Comment: json parsing could also be the culprit for this slow execution, anyways if it is that intense i suggest doing it in background. anyways the method i suggested would help in that too.

Comment: I did it background like this: **before** in I used to like this: `await storeCategoryDefect(_url, tokens);` **now** i removed await. but my listView data is missing